# Ghostscript install on Windows

Tags: windows, ghostscript

I've installed Ghostscript on Windows  but there seems to be a bug. The executable gs9win64.exe won't run any commands.  Always gives me similar error messages. Even if I just give it:

```
GS> -h
```

(which should display the Help instructions), I get an error message:

```
Error:/ undefined in -h
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
    %interp_exit    .runexec2   --nostringval-  [etc.]

Dictionary stack:
    --dict:984/1684(ro)(G)--    --dict:0/20(G)--    --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file positon is 3
```

My operating system is Windows 8.1.  System type is x64-based PC.  It has one processor installed: Intel64 Family 6.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript commands do not start with a hyphen, and `h` is not a command.

You should use the command `help` :

[image]

Comment: OK.  I think I'm ready to roll now.  The problem was I looked in the documentation (/gs/gs9.23/doc/Use.htm) and it was showing me command line invocations, but I was trying to enter them as commands in the window that comes up when you run gswin64.exe.

From the Windows CMD.EXE command line, this:
    
    gswin64c -h

does actually give help.

Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer has led you to a solution, please mark it using the V button.